# Is the Epanechnikov kernel really computationally more efficient that the Gaussian kernel?

Tags: r, statistics, kernel-density

I am implementing a function to estimate a kernel density estimation in the univariate and multivariate cases. For that matter I am using the Gaussian kernel and it works quite well even with massive datasets. Yet many people claim that I should use the Epanechnikov kernel because it is more computationally efficient, because of the compact support. But I do not agree, or, at least, I have not found a way to implement it so that it beats the Gaussian.
This is my code for the Gaussian estimation of the density at point x_o in the reals, with respect to a vector of values x:

```
dens_point <- function(x_0, x, width){
  weights <- (1/sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(1/2)*(((x_0-x)/width)^2))
  return((1/(length(x)*width))*sum(weights))
}
```

Or even more efficient,

```
dens_point <- function(x_0, x, width){
  constant <- (1/sqrt(2*pi)
  weights <- constant*exp(-0.5*(((x_0-x)/width)^2)))
  return((1/(length(x)*width))*sum(weights))
}
```

or still further, at the expense of readability:

```
dens_point <- function(x_0, x, width){
  constant <- (1/sqrt(2*pi)
  return(
     (1/(length(x)*width))*sum(constant*exp(-0.5*(((x_0-x)/width)^2))))
  )
}
```

To obtain the line on an interval I simply vectorise the function on the argument `x_0` and give it a sequence of values. This is as efficient as I can bring it. On comparison, the Epanechnikov kernel is much slower. I have tried the following code:

```
epanechnikov <- function(u){
  if (u <= 1){
    return(0)
  } else {
    return( (1-u^2)*0.75 )
  }
}
epanechnikov <- Vectorize(epanechnikov)

dens_point <- function(x0, x, width){
  weights <- epanechnikov( (x0-x)/width )
  return( (1/(length(x)*width)*sum(weights) )
}
```

But this solution is extremely inferior compared to the Gaussian, yet it is the most refined expression I can think of. For loops and sapplies are even slower. I would say that the Gaussian function is extremely fast because it uses the base R vector operations, which is something that Vectorize() cannot compete with. Can you come up with a faster code?

Comment: To exploit the bounded support of Epanechnikov kernels, one would need to be able to efficiently determine which points fall into the support (so you exclude any others). Doing so probably implies a specialized structure (maybe a kind of tree) for storing the data points, so that finding the ones in limited region doesn't require scanning all of the points (since otherwise you're back to number of operations proportional to the number of data). Going to that much trouble probably implies pretty large data sets (millions to billions).

Comment: @RobertDodier I pretty much agree. My best alternative would be maybe to first sort the values, then start calculating the weights, and when a point is reached where the last value was strictly positive and the present one is equal to zero, then stop and give all the following points a zero value.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `Vectorize` cannot compete with vectorized functions. So, just utilize base functions:

```
epanechnikov2 <- function(u) {
  k <- (1-u^2) * 0.75
  k[u <= 1] <- 0
  k
}
```

Or slightly faster [edit: and uses less memory]:

```
epanechnikov3 <- function(u) {
  k <- (1-u^2) * 0.75
  (abs(k) + k) / 2
}
```

Comment: Well that's an ingenious, but the Gaussian kernel is still at least as efficient as the functions you have defined. I would say that the advantage of the Epanechnikov's compact support is that you do not need to calculate ```(1-u^2) * 0.75``` for those ```u>=1```. Using your answer you still have to compute ```(1-u^2) * 0.75``` for all the elements anyways, so there's no victory in terms of computing power. But it is a step in that direction I guess.

Comment: @morphicphicus Yeah, that's a fair point. One option would be to move to C++ (i.e. `Rcpp`); I don't have the time to write it right now, but if no one responds soon I can give it a try later.

Comment: Does the computational cost of computing exponentials enter into this comparison?  `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(exp(-x^2), 1-x^2)` says that the polynomial takes about 75% as much time ...